# How do I efficiently extract meaningful data from a PDF with a set structure?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, pdf, itext

[image]I've been working on an application to help manage a Health Management Organization departments.
Its my first commercial piece of software and I'm excited about rounding up this week if I can get this issue sorted out.
Here's the problem...
The MIS department receives a PDF 4 times a year. This PDF contains 2 pieces of information.

a) A list of all hospitals registered under the orgnanisation.

b) A list of Enrollee's registered under each hospital.

I was tasked with writing a program that retrieve's all hospitals in the PDF, registering them in the application's database, then retrieving all enrollee's and registering them in the database under their respective hospitals(This is managed using a foreign key relationship in the database).

I used Regex to write a solution that registers all the hospitals, and save for some delay when parsing the PDF(which is 4000 pages long) it works perfectly.

The problem is that my solution to register the enrollee's is not as efficient as it should be, about 2 out of 10 enrollee's don't get registered due to inefficiencies in my code.

And when I transfer the already partially working solution to the client's server where it will finally reside, I get an error which says "Source Code Could Not Be Found". But when I run it in debug mode to check what the problem might be, it extracts the enrollee details as expected. So I'm very confused about that.

If I can get help with a)The "source code cannot be found" error or b)Why my code works on my development machine but not the server I would be very grateful.

Ill include my code and would also include a snapshot of the PDF as well but I doubt stack lets attachments with questions.

Thanks.

```
private void extractEnrolleesFromPDF(string enrolleeExtraction, string hospital)
    {
        int start;
        int end;
        string substring;

        try
        {
            MatchCollection policyNumbers = Regex.Matches(enrolleeExtraction, @"(\*)(\d{8})(\*)");

            foreach (var policyNumber in policyNumbers)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(enrolleeExtraction, "\\" + policyNumber.ToString());
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    //Strore the first occurence of the enrollee's policy number
                    start = match.Index;

                    Match match2 = Regex.Match(enrolleeExtraction.Substring(start + 10), @"(\*)");
                    if (match2.Success)
                    {
                        end = match2.Index + 9;

                        substring = enrolleeExtraction.Substring(start, end);

                        enrolleePolicyNumber.Add(substring);
                    }                        
                }
            }
            //Extract enrollee data an insert into the database

            ArrayList individualEnrolees = new ArrayList();

            int numberOfEnrollees = enrolleePolicyNumber.Count;
            bool principal = false;
            string fName;
            string lName;
            DateTime dob;
            string sex;
            string hospitalCode = hospital.Substring(1, 7);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEnrollees; i++)
            {
                string enrolleePolNumber;
                Match policyNumber = Regex.Match(enrolleePolicyNumber[i].ToString(), @"((\*)(\d{8})(\*))");
                if (policyNumber.Success)
                {
                    enrolleePolNumber = policyNumber.Value;
                }
                MatchCollection enrolleeRecords = Regex.Matches(enrolleePolicyNumber[i].ToString(), @"(\d{1})(\s)(\D*)(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})");

                //Empty the array list each time to avoid going over the same recors over and over again
                individualEnrolees.Clear();

                foreach (var record in enrolleeRecords)
                {
                    individualEnrolees.Add(record);
                }

                //The way our search works at the moment is that is uses the pattern *-------* at th ebeginning and end to
                //mark where an enrolleee's records begin and end. The problem now is that the last record does not have
                //that pattern at the end. So we need to find a way to retrieve the last record and add it to the collection we parse
                //for the enrollee data.
                try
                {
                    Match lastPolicyNumberInHospital = Regex.Match(enrolleeExtraction, @"(\*)(\d{8})(\*)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

                    string lastRecord = enrolleeExtraction.Substring(lastPolicyNumberInHospital.Index);

                    enrolleePolicyNumber.Add(lastRecord);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to extract last record: " + ex.Message);
                }

                foreach (var record in individualEnrolees)
                {
                    string princ;

                    string[] splitEnrolleeData = record.ToString().Split(' ');

                    //int splitSectionCount counts how many section our split enrollee data is
                    int splitSectionCount = splitEnrolleeData.Count();

                    //if we have six sections then we expect the Principal or Spouse record to be
                    //on index 1
                    if (splitSectionCount == 5)
                    {
                        princ = splitEnrolleeData[1].ToString();
                        if (princ == "Principal")
                        {
                            principal = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            principal = false;
                        }
                    }
                    //if we have five sections then we expect the Principal or Spouse record to be
                    //on index 0.
                    //i.e. Merged with the serial number so we check to see if it contains
                    //the string "Principal" or "Spouse"
                    else if (splitSectionCount == 4)
                    {
                        if (splitEnrolleeData[0].ToString().Contains("0"))
                        {
                            principal = true;
                        }
                        else if (!splitEnrolleeData[0].ToString().Contains("0"))
                        {
                            principal = false;
                        }
                    }
                    //TO-DO: Eliminate this comment block is else-if above works properly
                    //princ = splitEnrolleeData[1].ToString();
                    //if (princ == "Principal")
                    //{
                    //    principal = true;
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    principal = false;
                    //}

                    enrolleePolNumber = policyNumber.Value.Substring(1, policyNumber.Value.Length - 2);

                    //if we have 6 sections as expected carry on and register the enrollee as usual
                    //if not, if we have 5 do something else
                    //this is because some enrollees in the NHIS PDF arent split properly returning 
                    //5 items instead of 6
                    if (splitSectionCount == 5)
                    {
                        lName = splitEnrolleeData[2].ToString();
                        fName = splitEnrolleeData[3].ToString();
                        dob = Convert.ToDateTime(splitEnrolleeData[4].ToString());
                        hosp = getHospitalID(hospitalCode);
                        if (principal == true)
                        {
                            if (checkIfPolicyNumberExists(enrolleePolNumber) == false)
                            {
                                registerEnrollee(enrolleePolNumber, fName, lName, dob, hosp.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else if (principal == false)
                        {
                            if (checkIfDependantPolicyNumberExists(enrolleePolNumber, fName) == false)
                            {
                                registerDependant(enrolleePolNumber, fName, lName, dob, hosp.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (splitSectionCount == 4)
                    {
                        lName = splitEnrolleeData[1].ToString();
                        fName = splitEnrolleeData[2].ToString();
                        dob = Convert.ToDateTime(splitEnrolleeData[3].ToString());
                        hosp = getHospitalID(hospitalCode);
                        if (principal == true)
                        {
                            if (checkIfPolicyNumberExists(enrolleePolNumber) == false)
                            {
                                registerEnrollee(enrolleePolNumber, fName, lName, dob, hosp.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else if (principal == false)
                        {
                            if (checkIfDependantPolicyNumberExists(enrolleePolNumber, fName) == false)
                            {

                                    registerDependant(enrolleePolNumber, fName, lName, dob, hosp.ToString());

                                //else if (!parentExists(enrolleePolNumber))
                                //{

                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Error retrieving subsitring: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Although you wrote a long question, the information that is needed to answer the question is missing. Your question is marked iTextSharp, yet there is no iTextSharp code that shows how you're extracting the content. There is also no sample of the extracted data, so we don't know if the problem is caused by the RegEx or by missing data before the RegEx is performed. You also combined two questions in one: you are asking about a configuration problem (missing code) and a programming problem (missing data).

Comment: Also note that iText Software has customers who have solved the exact same problem you are describing. You are aware that you or your customer should be an iText Software customer if you choose iTextSharp in this project, aren't you? If so, please create a support ticket at iText Software, because IMHO your question goes beyond the support you can expect on StackOverflow (but whoever doesn't agree is obviously free to provide an answer).

Comment: Along with what @BrunoLowagie said, the message "Source Code Could Not Be Found" is not part of iText. To fix that message, go to the source of the code that has that message and look for the conditions that need to be met and work back from there.